# Bind <select> to form in Playframework 2

Tags: java, model-view-controller, scala, playframework-2.0

How should I handle form requests with select elements in Playframework 2.0?

I have a form with this select:

```
@helper.select(deviceForm("deviceType"), options = options(deviceTypeList))
```

`DeviceType` is binded to `public DeviceType deviceType;` but `deviceTypeList` is a list of `Strings`

Comment: What is `DeviceType`? An enum? How do you generate the `deviceTypeList`?

Comment: DeviceType is a class. I generate deviceTypeList by fetching the list of DeviceTypes and use the attributes of DeviceType to generate the String list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [register a custom data binder](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms) for your type `DeviceType`:

```java
Formatters.register(DeviceType.class, new Formatters.SimpleFormatter<DeviceType>() {

    @Override
    public DeviceType parse(String input, Locale l) throws ParseException {
        return …
    }

    @Override
    public String print(DeviceType deviceType, Locale l) {
        return …
    }
});
```